# Robolectric 3.0 - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable when testing library module

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, robolectric

I recently upgraded my `Robolectric` from **2.4** to **3.0-rc3** and after a lot of wrestling with it, I've narrowed it down to this last error where a few cases fail because of this **issue:**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable
```

It passes like 99% of the cases, but a few are failing because of this. The other components of my application all pass with flying colors, and I've only seen it happen in my module.

I looked it up and it seems that the problem stems from `Robolectrie 3.0` not generating the `R.java` files. However, there didn't seem to be a solution for it, save for some `build.gradle` hack that didn't work for me. I also already tried editing `targetSDK`s and making sure the `AppCompat` theme was set in the manifest, to no avail.

**build.gradle:**

```
apply from: rootProject.file('src/build/groovy/android-library.gradle')

dependencies {
    compile project(':myApplication')

    compile('com.application:player:') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}


    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0"
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0"
}
```

Does anybody have any idea how to fix this? It's sinking a lot of my time!

Comment: There is an open Robolectric issue here: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1796

Comment: One thing I do see here is you should use `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0` and the v4 version should be the same but it is already included in `appcompat`. Make sure your `cardview` is upgraded as well.

Answer (score 0):

Robolectric 3.0 has started to separate several shadow classes out into different artifacts. You probably just need to add `shadows-support-v4` as a dependency (while keeping the `*-v7` dependencies from `com.android.support`).

Comment: Probably? Have you tested this?

Comment: I'm saying "probably" because I also had a `NoClassDefFoundError` but for a different class, and I was able to resolve it by adding `shadows-httpclient` to the list of dependencies. The OP is in the best position to actually test this.

Answer (score 0):

I had experienced the same issue.

This is what I did to remediate it.

Assume you have included following libraries
    support-v4, com.android.support.v7's appcompat lib, robolectric 3.0 and junit and the reference to the apkib you are testing (as per sschuberth and other contributors of this thread)

Suppose the activity under test is `XXXActivity`. 
In order to populate our context in our unit test case - we utilize 
    `Robolectric.buildActivity(XXXActivity.class).create().start().resume().get();`

I changed it to 
    `Robolectric.buildActivity(XXXMockActivity.class).create().start().resume().get();`

where `XXXMockActivity` merely sets a theme before invoking the `super.onCreate()`.

```
public class XXXMockActivity extends XXXActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_DarkActionBar);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: Yes, I tested this before 3.0 became stable. Not tested with the latest 3.0 stable version

Comment: This doesn't work for me because compilation fails (R not found)

Answer (score 0):

I simply ignored the test - there doesn't seem to be a solution for this problem. As someone commented on my original question, this is an open issue found here:  github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1796

If you're having the same problem, I wouldn't spend too much time on it.

Comment: I posted that issue in the comments. I think you should just wait. This happens in only my library projects.